# Which parameter data type is used in the Integrate geoprocessing tool for ranking?

Tags: python, arcpy, geoprocessing

I'm trying to figure out which [parameter data type](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Defining_parameter_data_types_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000035000000/) is used in, for example, the Integrate geoprocessing tool.

It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to use it in a geoprocessing tool I'm making, but can't figure out which data type it is.

Comment: It's a pair like "FeatureClass,rank;FeatureClass2,rank2" the best way to tell is put it into a model with some sample values then export to a python script that way you can tell if it's spaces, commas, python list or semi colons.. parameter pairs aren't 100% consistent.

Comment: I know it's a pair, but can I get something that looks like that in a tool I create? I don't know if there is a data type in the parameter list I can use to get that same box in my tool.

Comment: Now that *is* a good question. I've never tried.

Comment: What about GPValueTable, there's an example here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Defining_parameters_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000028000000/ showing what you're after. Yes, it's a long list and some of the values aren't very descriptive. Mostly I use the same dozen types.

Comment: Interesting, that is definitely it. Thanks! Apparently, that data type can only be used in a Python toolbox, so I guess this will be my first run with that. If you'll add the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *looong list* of types there is GPValueTable which has an example [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Defining_parameters_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000028000000/):

[image]

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName='Input Features',
        name='in_features',
        datatype='GPValueTable',
        parameterType='Required',
        direction='Input')

    param0.columns = [['Feature Layer', 'Features'], ['Long', 'Ranks']]
```